# PHPUnit being installed to the wrong directory

Tags: php, linux, installation, phpunit, pear

I recently installed PHPUnit using the pear package installer as directed in the documentation. Pear is currently installed in `/usr/local/lib/php/pear`. However, PHPUnit seems to be installing itself into `/usr/share/pear` and therefore I get include errors when I try to run `phpunit --version` or `phpunit --help`.

I see three possible solutions, but I am afraid of running into problems later on if I choose the wrong one. Here are the possible solutions: (A)  move the PHPUnit directory from `/usr/share/pear/PHPUnit` to `/usr/local/lib/php/pear/PHPUnit`, (B) move the PHPUnit directory to `/usr/local/lib/php/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit`, or (C) reinstall phpunit using some extra command or switch, to get it to install to the proper location?

Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE: **Here is the output of `pear config-show` when run under my username:**

```
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    1
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /usr/local/lib/php/pear/docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /usr/lib64/php/modules
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/local/lib/php
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /usr/share/pear/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /usr/local/lib/php/pear/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /tmp/pear/download
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/temp
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /usr/local/lib/php/pear/tests
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /usr/share/pear/www
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            27
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /etc/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /home/webdeveloper/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /etc/pear.conf
```

**And here is the output of `pear config-show` when run as root:**

```
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    1
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /usr/share/pear/docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /usr/lib64/php/modules
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/share/pear
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /usr/share/pear/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /usr/share/pear/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /tmp/pear/download
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/temp
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /usr/share/pear/tests
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /usr/share/pear/www
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            22
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /etc/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /root/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /etc/pear.conf
```

Comment: Seem to be an issue with your pear. Can you add the output of `pear config-show` maybe?

Comment: It seems strange that PEAR would be configured to put its configuration files and www files in `/usr/share/pear` whereas everything else goes under `/usr/local/lib/php`. For me (Ubuntu 11.04) everything goes under `/usr/share/php`. How did you install PHP and PEAR? What distro are you using?

Comment: @DavidHarkness Our old sysadmin installed php, originally configured `--without-pear`. I worked with the new sysadmin to install pear (following the pear manual instructions) into `/usr/local/lib/php/pear` and I wouldn't be surprised if we missed an option that then defaulted to `/usr/share/pear`. We are running Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 9).

Comment: Hm, config seems fine so far. You use installing the pear package as root and is the output of the `config-show` from the root account too?

Comment: @edorian Whoops, that's the output of `config-show` my account instead of root. It was installed as root. I'll update it as soon as I can get our sysadmin to run it and send me the results.

Comment: @edorian Ok, I have updated my question with both versions of `pear config-show`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, seems we have found the issue (see the comments).

I would assume `PHPUnit` was installed as root or pear is for some reason picking up the "roots" config dir.

The path where the code is put is defined in:

```
 PEAR directory  php_dir /usr/share/pear
```

So something in the pear config seems to be the issue.

If possible I'd `pear config-set php_dir $yourLocation` and see if it works out then.

---

[**`It is possible to install multiple versions of PHPUnit`**](http://tech.vg.no/2011/11/29/running-multiple-versions-of-phpunit/) using `pear install --installroot /some/path/` like described in the post. So that should work out no matter what.